# Is there a way to have access my postgreSQL database online like MongoDB?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, hosting, database-migration, heroku-postgres

I had to migrate my database from MongoDB to PostgreSQL.
The inconvenient is that everytime I add modifications in my local database, I have to go through a backup file creation and import it on my Heroku postgreSQL.

I would like to reduce the steps.
Ideally I would like to have an online database so that I won't have to worry about data migration, like it was for MongoDB.
Is there any solution like this ?

Comment: If you need the changes in Heroku, why don't you just make the changes in Heroku?  Heroku **is** an online database.  We don't know what it was like for MongoDB.  Like PostgreSQL, MongoDB can be configured in a variety of ways, and you have not described what MongoDB was like for you.

Comment: With Mongo I didn't have to go through the CLI to make change. I could use the app MongoDB Compass and see all my data, export/import and make changes in real time.
On Heroku PostgreSQL I can't see my data (collections and fields). Which also means when I add data on local, it will automatically appear online.

Comment: Nevermind I just found out how to to it. What you said was logical.
Thanks.